# How to generate a username using slice

Tags: javascript, html, slice

I am trying to generate a username by using the slice method. I am trying to use the users First name and last name to generate a username. Can't seem to make it work.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<html>
<body>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var Firstname = document.getElementById("Firstname");  
        var LastName = document.getElementById("LastName");   
        var nameId = (Firstname.slice(1,3)+LastName.slice(0,3));
    }

    </script>

   <p><input type="text" name="Firstname" id="Firstname" ></p><br/>
   <p><input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" ></p> 
   <p id="nameId"></p>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're selecting the text from an input field, you'll need to add `.value`

So:

```
var Firstname = document.getElementById("Firstname").value;  
var LastName = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the element with getElementById.

Try using document.getElementById("Firstname").value to get the value in your element.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the values, as pointed by Nick R, but you missed the last point : assigning your `nameId` value to the HTML content.

Add this in your `myFunction()` :

```
document.getElementById("nameId").innerHTML=nameId;
```

Comment: I cant, sorry. I dont have enough reputation.